# How to implement Poisson Regression?

Tags: python, statistics, regression

There are 2 types of Generalized Linear Models:
 
1. Log-Linear Regression, also known as Poisson Regression
 
2. Logistic Regression

How to implement the Poisson Regression in Python for Price Elasticity prediction?

Comment: Is this somewhat what you're looking for http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/glm.html? Also, way too broad.

Comment: The link you shared has the "Poisson distribution". I was looking for "Poisson Regression". It is there in R, but how to implement it in Python ?

Comment: I am not looking for Logistic Regression. Wanted to know about Log-Linear (Poisson) Regression in Python.

Comment: @IljaEverilä sure logistic regression will help a lot in a poisson regression problem. Don't add comments that make no sense. Better stay silent

Comment: @Altons that's true, removed.

Comment: The scenario is a predictive model has to be built for Price Elasticity prediction. So was keen on knowing about Poisson Regression using Python.

Comment: @Laurel wouldn't you use logistic or probit regression for Price elasticity?

Comment: @Alton, I don't know much about probit regression. I'll try Logistic Regression as I have a fair understanding about it.

Comment: But Logistic Regression is the same as a classification problem.

Comment: @Laurel Price elasticity modeling builds a model in which the actual response is the individuals acceptance or rejection of a quote or renewal offering so logistic reg will fit well if  you're modelling the acceptance or rejection of a price offer - don't quote 100% here as I haven't done this type of modelling since Univ (loooong time ago)

Comment: @Altons I wanted to predict the estimated price value using a model. Regarding acceptance/rejection of renewal offering, as you said Logistic Regression works out pretty well. I'll consider doing the acceptance/ rejection concept.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at the [statmodels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels) package in python.

Here is an [example](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/umich.box.com/shared/static/ir0bnkup9rywmqd54zvm.ipynb)

A bit more of input to avoid the ***link only answer***

Assumming you know python here is an extract of the example I mentioned earlier.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations import GEE
from statsmodels.genmod.cov_struct import (Exchangeable,
    Independence,Autoregressive)
from statsmodels.genmod.families import Poisson
```

`pandas` will hold the data frame with the data you want to use to feed your poisson model.
`statsmodels` package contains large family of statistical models such as Linear, probit, poisson etc. from here you will import the Poisson family model (hint: see last import)

The way you fit your model is as follow (assuming your dependent variable is called `y` and your IV are age, trt and base):

```
fam = Poisson()
ind = Independence()
model1 = GEE.from_formula("y ~ age + trt + base", "subject", data, cov_struct=ind, family=fam)
result1 = model1.fit()
print(result1.summary())
```

As I am not familiar with the nature of your problem I would suggest to have a look at negative binomial regression if you need to count data is well overdispersed. with High overdispersion your poisson assumptions may not hold.

Plethora of info for poisson regression in R - just google it.

Hope now this answer helps.

Comment: Sorry what is "subject" here?

Comment: Is "subject" the dependent variable?

Comment: Sorry I did not see these comments. "Subject" is a grouping variable. dependent variable is 'y'

Answer (score 6):

If I am not mistaken, @Altons' answer is for [GEEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation), which assume some sort of grouped structure. The common Poisson Regression (without a need for a group, such as "subject") is implemented as General Linear Model in `statsmodels`:

```
import patsy
import statsmodels as sm
from statsmodels.genmod.families import Poisson


fam = Poisson()
f = 'some_count ~ some_numeric_variable + C(some_categorical_variable)'
y, X = patsy.dmatrices(f, data, return_type='matrix')

p_model = sm.GLM(y, X, family=fam)

result = p_model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

The variables used in the formula are just placeholders for variables in the DataFrame `data`.

Comment: when to use "C" and when not? is it to be used on label-encoded and one-hot encoded columns too?

Comment: C should be used if the variable type is categorical. This is usually the case for label-encoded and one-hot variables.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, can you point me to some documentation to learn more on writing these formulaes please?!

Comment: For anyone new to the statsmodels package, make sure you change line 2 to "import statsmodels.api as sm". It will error without the ".api".